# iOS 16 + Firebase: The app references non-public selectors determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, app-store-connect, ios16

I am trying to submit native app using Xcode to the App Store.
The app is built with Firebase and SwiftUI for iOS 16.
The submission finishes with the following warning:

**The app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp: determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails:, transform:**

I am not doing anything in my code with this API.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better for Firebase issues https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you got a solution?

Comment: The upload will be processed anyway, just wait a bit.

Comment: @user7289922 whether you were able to solve this?

Comment: @Ranjit The app was submitted sucesfully.
Upgrade to Firebase 8.1.1 to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed in Firebase 8.1.1

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8222

Comment: I have the same error and have Firebase 8.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it by using another machine running Xcode 13.4.1, with bitcode enabled. It seems to be related to Xcode 14 deprecating bitcode.